# how to upload byte array in netcore

Tags: upload, asp.net-core, webclient, webclient.uploaddata

this example code in netframework 4.6

```
byte[] myByte = etc;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Clear();
webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ChannelAccessToken);

var a1 = webClient.DownloadData("https://api.myweb.com/1");
var b1 = webClient.UploadData("https://api.myweb.com/2", myByte );
```

In net framework i can use this code to upload byte array to link web its my want to upload/download now i need to change to write net core how can i write this code in net core?